# Array values from form

Tags: php, arrays, forms, radio-group

I have a form which contains up to 10 sets of radio buttons. The radio button provides an answer to a question. All questions are populated from a database and on completion, the database is updated with the fields user_id, question_number & answer_value. I am using an array but only one answer_value seems to pass to the form processor.

This is my code

```
    <form action="new-answers.php" method="post" id="my_answer">    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input name="answer_value[]" type="radio" required="required" value="1">&nbsp;Totally false for me&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input name="answer_value[]" type="radio" required="required" value="2">&nbsp;Partially false for me&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input name="answer_value[]" type="radio" required="required" value="3">&nbsp;Indifferent/neutral&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input name="answer_value[]" type="radio" required="required" value="4">&nbsp;Partially true for me&nbsp;</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input name="answer_value[]" type="radio" required="required" value="5">&nbsp;Totally true for me&nbsp;</label>
```

This is what I'm using in the form processor page

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$i=0;

$user=$_POST['user_id'];
$question=$_POST['question_number'];
$answer = $_POST['answer_value']; 
// open the mysqli prepared statement globally
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('INSERT INTO answers (user_id,question_number,answer_value) VALUES (?, ?,?)');

function insertAnswer($user, $question, $answer) {
    global $stmt;

    // using prepared statement several times with different variables
    if (
        $stmt &&
        $stmt -> bind_param('iii', $user, $question,$answer) &&
        $stmt -> execute()
    ) {
        // new answers added
    }

}
}
```

Even when I try just echoing using

```
$answer = $_POST['answer_value'];

foreach($answer as $value) {
    echo $value.'<br />';
}
```

I get only answer.

Comment: You need to give the different groups of radio buttons different names, otherwise they all belong to one single group, and that means the user can only check one single radio button out of _all_ of them to begin with.

Comment: Where are your questions?

Comment: Hey, OP, shall we consider you know when to use radio buttons and checkboxes?

Comment: 04FS I thought that by using an array it would give each group of them a different name. I tried naming them as e.g. answer_value1, answer_value2 for each group but when they come through on the $_POST I can't figure a way to strip them in order to assign them to the variable in my MySQL insert statement.

Zain Farooq The questions are just a line of text above, that asks them to rate a statement.

Rahul Meshram I want to use radio buttons not checkboxes